# spring boot with gradle not starting up

Tags: spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build sample hello application using gradle build in Spring tool suite facing below design time error.

I have grade version 4.10.2 installed on my machine.

Error Msg:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-bin.zip'.
Build file 'C:\TFS\Study\Springboot\GradleExamples\workspace\Gradle_Hello\build.gradle' line: 14
Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'] was not found in any of the following sources:
- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.1.2.RELEASE')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'] was not found in any of the following sources:
- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.1.2.RELEASE')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository    build.gradle    /Gradle_Hello   line 14 Gradle Error Marker
```

Answer (score 1):

Next time, please include your build.gradle file.

I believe your problem is caused by the fact you are trying to apply the plugin:'org.springframework.boot' without telling your gradle script where to find that plugin. Your buildscript (build.gradle file) actually depends on the org.springframework.boot plugin, however since it can't find it (and doesn't even know what it is), you are getting this issue.

you can fix that issue by adding the following code at the top of your file:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
      // You are telling gradle that this script (Not the project) depends on the 
      // following plugin
      classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.2.RELEASE"
   }
}

apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"

// The rest of your build.gradle file
```

Comment: hi,i have the same in my build.grade file but still throwing error

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include your original build.gradle file as well as the one you used after applying my answer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I changed to Gradle 6.5 and also add settings.gradle file in the same dir as your build.gradle with the following info.

// settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    plugins {
        id "org.springframework.cloud.contract" version "${verifierVersion}"
    }
    repositories {
        // to pick from local .m2
        mavenLocal()
        // for snapshots
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        // for milestones
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        // for GA versions
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```

In addition make sure that you can connect to your repositories. In my case if was a internal nexus server and gradle wasn't able to connect to the repositories because of SSL certificate missing from JDK truststore. I added the nexus SSL certificate in to the JDK truststore and it resolved